# feed single .jpg file true carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, image, upload, carrierwave

Would it be possible to feed a single.jpg true carrierwave? 
Using jpegcam Im generating a temp.jpg and would like to feed this in carrierwave
so it gets stored in the photos table and generate the thumbnails based on the /uploaders/photo_uploader.rb

Any way to feed a single jpg to carrierwave?

```
  def upload
    File.open(upload_path, 'w:ASCII-8BIT') do |f|
      f.write request.raw_post
    end
    render :text => "ok"
  end

  private

  def upload_path # is used in upload and create 
    file_name = ("webcam_1.jpg")
    File.join(::Rails.root.to_s, 'public', 'uploads', file_name)
    Photo.create(:file => File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/#{file_name}"))
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you just want to create a Photo from a file? Assuming your Photo class has an 'image' field that Carrierwave is using, that would be this:

```
Photo.create(:image => File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/#{file_name}"))
```

Comment: thx! this almost works, only now I'm getting a TypeError (can't convert Photo into String):
  app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:21:in `initialize'
  app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:21:in `open'
  app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:21:in `upload' This could might be cause I used a paperclip tutorial and tried to migrate to carrierwave, I will try in my main app thx

Comment: Obviously debugging from limited information is tricky, but my best guess is that if you're using the line as I wrote it, file_name is a Photo object instead of a string?